# this in event handlers for another object

Tags: javascript

Class A (mine) implements event handlers for class B (3rd party). Within these event handlers, I would like to access class A's properties.

Using *this* in class A's handlers does not work because it references class B's scope.

Global variables seem like the only option. Am I missing a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to bind your event handlers to your object!

You first need the add the `bind` method to any function object. Use this code:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(scope) {
  var func = this;

  return function() {
    return func.apply(scope, arguments);
  }
}
```

Now you can register your `class B` event handlers to your `class A` methods this way:

```
var a = new A();
var b = new B();

b.registerEvent(a.eventHandlerMethod.bind(a));
```

This way any references to `this` within the code of `A.eventHandlerMethod` will point to object `a`.

If you need a deeper understanding of this stuff you can read this great article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations/

Another article: http://alternateidea.com/blog/articles/2007/7/18/javascript-scope-and-binding

Answer (score 5):

Create a `self` or `that` variable, which holds a reference to `this`. Something like this:

```
var ClassA = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.MyProperty1 = 3;
    self.MyProperty2 = "hello world";

    var ClassB_EventHandler = function () {
        self.MyProperty1;
        self.MyProperty2;
    }

}
```

You can use `this` and `self` interchangeably in `ClassA`'s scope. In the `ClassB` event handler, you'll be required to use `self` to reference `ClassA` properties.

Comment: Should this work with prototype? I initially tried this and it did not seem to work.