# javascript object undefined under anonymous function

Tags: javascript, object

Let's first take a look at JavaScript code =>

```
function ConstructNodes(className,hiddenId,alertMsg,formName){
    this.className = className;
    this.hiddenId  = hiddenId;
    this.alertMsg  = alertMsg;
    this.formName  = formName;
}

ConstructNodes.prototype.getId = function(){
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName(this.className);
    for (var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
        nodes[i].onclick = function(){
            var r = confirm(this.alertMsg);
            if (r==true){
                alert(this.hiddenId); // undefined
            } else {
                return;
            }
        };
    }
};

var obj = new ConstructNodes("className","hiddenId","Are you sure ?","formName");
obj.getId();
```

My problem in this situation is that defined objects are undefined under getId's anonymous function , how can I solve this situation ? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [this in event handlers for another object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079703/this-in-event-handlers-for-another-object)

Comment: @FelixKling how it is duplicate when I've nothing to do with implementing classes

Comment: @Tornike , your `function ConstructNodes` is the class

Comment: @caligula sure , but I've not another class

Comment: @Tornike the problem is that your code expects `this` inside the event handlers set up by the "getId()" function to be the same as it is outside the handlers. It will not be.

Comment: @Tornike , you do have another object. This is the DOM object `nodes[i]`. And you have attached a handler to its `click` event. Inside this handler your `this` is the DOM object, not `obj`

Comment: @caligula yes, it is DOM object inside anonymous function

Comment: @caligula now understand why this question is same like it was mentioned above , thanks guys

Comment: I have to agree, there might be better duplicates but the solution is essentially the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is incorrectly assuming that `this` will refer to a "ConstructNodes" object inside the event handlers. It won't; it'll be the element.  Instead, store `this` in an object, and things will be better:

```
ConstructNodes.prototype.getId = function(){
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName(this.className), obj = this;
    for (var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
        nodes[i].onclick = function(){
            var r = confirm(obj.alertMsg);
            if (r==true){
                alert(obj.hiddenId); // undefined
                document.getElementById(obj.hiddenId).value = this.id;
                alert(obj.hiddenId);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

(It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, so there may be some issues still.)

Answer (score 1):

It took me a minute to understand your question.

You cannot refer to `this` in an anonymous function in getId. 
you must save `this` into a variable for example `var me = this` outside the anonymous function, and then use `me.hiddenId`.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMu7q/1/) to demonstrate that.

Comment: That is completely irrelevant.

Comment: You are right - I misunderstood the question. I fixed the answer and the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

It's `undefined` because you can not access `this` in that function just like that.
Any function is called with it's own *execution context*, thus the `this` in that case is something different than outside of the function.

You can solve that by defining a `var` in the outer scope and access it in the inner, like this:

```
function ConstructNodes(className,hiddenId,alertMsg,formName){
  this.className = className;
  this.hiddenId  = hiddenId;
  this.alertMsg  = alertMsg;
  this.formName  = formName;
}

ConstructNodes.prototype.getId = function() {
  var _this = this; // a reference that will be known in your closure/function
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName(this.className);
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].onclick = function(){
      if (confirm(_this.alertMsg)) {
        alert(_this.hiddenId); // no longer undefined
      } else {
        return;
      }
    };
  }
};

var obj = new ConstructNodes("className", "hiddenId", "Are you sure?", "formName")
obj.getId();
```